# How can I show that ($sec(x)sin (x)) – tan (x) = cos (x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

$(1/cos(x) - tan (x) * sin(x) = cos(x)$

$(1/cos(x) - (sin (x) / cos(x)) * (sin(x) / 1) = cos(x)$

And then at this point, I become completely lost. I am new to this and not even exactly sure if I am even on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $sec(x) = \frac{1}{cos(x)}$ and that $tan(x)\cdot sin(x) = \frac{sin^2(x)}{cos(x)}$
Rewriting our original equation:
$$
sec(x) - tan(x)\cdot sin(x) = {1 - sin^2(x) \over cos(x)} = {cos^2(x) \over cos(x)} = cos(x)
$$
We used the fact that $sin^2(x) + cos^2(x) = 1$ to change $1 - sin^2(x) = cos^2(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
sec(x)-tan(x)sin(x)=1/cos(x)-sin^2(x)/cos(x)
$$
Hence, 
$$1/cos(x)-sin^2(x)/cos(x)=1-sin^2(x)/cos(x)=(cos^2(x)+sin^2(x)-sin^2(x))/cos(x)=cos^2(x)/cos(x)=cos(x).$$ Done.

Answer (score 0):

(1/cos(x) - tan (x) * sin(x) = cos(x)

(1/cos(x) - (sin (x) / cos(x)) * (sin(x) / 1) = cos(x)

1/cos(x) * (1 - sin(x)^2) = cos(x)

But: cos(x)^2 + sin(x)^2 = 1

So

1/cos(x) * cos(x)^2 = cos(x)

cos(x) = cos(x)